# PHP auto correct date in specific format

Tags: php, date

In my code users post date in content. Which is may be in different formats the format which is used in majority auto sets in MySQL `date time` field format i.e. `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`. My problem is most of them have typo mistakes or different formats which my code doesn't pick correctly and it returns date something like this `1970-01-01 05:00:00`. I am in deep from this issue. Is there any function that auto corrects the date time even if there is a typo mistake in it and if time is not available it auto adds the time to it?

Here are some examples of different formats I get

```
30 September 2017 | 09 31 AM
29 September 2017 | 02:30 PM
27/07/2016 | 08:20 PM
19/09/2017| 01:32 PM
14-July-2017 03:31 PM
September 5 2017
April 7 2016 04:55 PM
```

Here is my current PHP code

```
$get_date = ""; //Date in text form
$show_dated = strtotime(str_replace('|', '', $get_date);
$get_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $show_dated);
echo $get_date;
```

Comment: Too broad. You need to find a way to enforce uniform dates and/or figure out what format a date is so you can parse it correctly.

Comment: @JohnConde that is the main problem I cannot enforce them and in case if I can enforce them I am unable to update previous posts because there are almost 15K older posts :(

Comment: @JohnConde if I get a possible solution for above given dates I can trace and fix others too because it will be easy for me to update about 2-3K posts in rest

Comment: Then you have a lot of work cut out for you. But, you can short circuit it often times by running a date through strtotime(), if it returns a timestamp you're all set, if not, only then do you have to worry about trying to parse it.

Comment: hmm you're right

Comment: @JohnConde If OP really has _no_ idea what date format can be used, then `strtotime()` could make some wrong assumptions. `27/07/2016` goes against the assumption that dates separated by slashes are in m/d/y format.  If a user using that format provided the 12th day instead of the 27th, the fact that we got a timestamp result does not mean it is correct.

Comment: @PatrickQ - Use `DateTime()` instead of `strtotime()` for a date like `27/07/2016`... it will throw an exception that can be trapped and handled

Comment: @MarkBaker Exactly. Much better to know that you don't know than to think you do and be wrong. That being said, I think OP is pretty much hosed unfortunately

Comment: @MarkBaker can you give me a link to follow or show me ab example?

Comment: [Link to follow](http://uk1.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php).

Comment: [Example](https://3v4l.org/R3fZh)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using date_parse() instead of strtotime(). I did this for a while, and it functioned better. Ultimately my solution was to build a custom parser based on the confused mess of user inputs. I eyeballed 2000 entries to develop a 'gold standard' set of results, and then fine-tuned an algorithm to match until it performed 100% correctly.